# Large MySQL Table - Advice Needed

Tags: mysql

I have a large mysql MyISAM table with 1.5mil rows and 4.5GB big, still increasing everyday.

I have done all the necessary indexing and the performance has been greatly optimized. Yet, the database occasionally break down (showing 500 Internal Server error) usually due to query overload. Whenever there is a break down, the table will start to work very slowly and I'll have to do a silly but effective task : copy the entire table over to a new table and replace the new one with the old one!!

You may ask why such a stupid action. Why not repair or optimize the table? I've tried that but the time to do repair or optimization may be more than the time to simply duplicate the table and more importantly the new table performs much faster.

Newly built table usually work very well. But over time, it will become sluggish (maybe after a month) and eventually lead to another break down (500 internal server). That's when everything slow down significantly and I need to repeat the silly process of replacing table.

For your info:
- The data in the table seldom get deleted. So there isn't a lot of overhead in the table.
- Under optimal condition, each query takes 1-3 secs. But when it becomes sluggish, the same query can take more than 30 seconds.
- The table has 24 fields, 7 are int, 3 are text, 5 are varchar and the rest are smallint. It's used to hold articles.

If you can explain what cause the sluggishness or you have suggestion on how to improve the situation, feel free to share it. I will be very thankful.

Comment: One question: Does this table use any variable-length rows?

Comment: can you post your query and "EXPLAIN" output?

Comment: To zebediah, other than int, text, varchar and smallint, this table does not use other types. Length in text may vary though.
To Maris, the table is well optimized through indexing. Every enquiry is done without the need of sorting. I used Explain to check every query to make sure every query is optimized.

Comment: From the asker's description, it contains 8 columns contributing to variable length rows...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider moving to InnoDB. One of its advantages is that it's crash safe. If you need full text capabilities, you can achieve that by implementing external tools like Sphinx or Lucene.

Comment: I always recommend InnoDB over ISAM, I skipped that, good recommendation.

Answer (score 1):

Partitioning is a common strategy here. You might be able to partition the articles by what month they were committed to the database (for example) and then have your query account for returning results from the month of interest (how you partition the table would be up to you and your application's design/behavior). You can union results if you will need your results to come from more than one table.

Even better, depending on your MySQL version, partitioning may be supported by your server. See [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/partitioning-overview.html) for details.

Comment: There will be a lot of cross referencing, for instance the generation of related posts for every article. This means most of the times the enquiry will require UNION of all partitioned tables. In view of this, is partition will a good choice?

Comment: Will it be doing this generation real time or batch? Is there a sane limit on how far back you can look for related posts? Is data frequently updated?

Comment: generation is real time. No limit on how far back. Data is frequently updated, daily actually, in batches.

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is being caused by dynamic width rows. You have a couple of strategies available to you, move the variable length columns onto a different table (won't resolve but will isolate the problem), switch to innodb, switch to fixed rowsize. Let me know how this goes!